# Can't install ruby 1.8.7 on Mac 10.8 via RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, ruby-1.8.7

I can't install ruby ree or ruby 1.8.7 on my Mac 10.8.2.

I did that:

```
$ brew install libksba
$ brew update
$ brew install autoconf automake
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
```

Then i try to install ruby 1.8.7 and i can't

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8.2/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p370.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Building 'ruby-1.8.7-p370' using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p370 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p370, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.7-p370 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p370 to /Users/serg/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p370
ruby-1.8.7-p370 - #extracted to /Users/serg/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p370
Applying patch /Users/serg/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch
Applying patch /Users/serg/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/no_sslv2.diff
ruby-1.8.7-p370 - #configuring
ruby-1.8.7-p370 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read /Users/serg/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p370/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
Ruby 'ruby-1.8.7-p370' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.
Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that requires        2 patches just to be compiled on up to date linux system.
This may have known and unaccounted for security vulnerabilities.
Please consider upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3-194 which will have all of the latest security patches.
MacBook-Pro-Serg-L-6:smartlearn serg$ rvm remove 1.8.7
Removing /Users/serg/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p370...
/Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370 has already been removed.
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p370 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p370 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p370 environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p370 binaries...
```

Error:

```
Error running 'make', please read /Users/serg/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p370/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Log from make.log is [here](http://pastebin.com/gm3aRCmr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

1. Remove Xcode.
2. From [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) I downloaded the package for Mountain Lion.
3. Install downloaded osx-gcc-installer.
4. Install Xcode (and command-line tools).

That is all.

Comment: This is an unacceptable solution for anyone who needs Xcode. Look above at @mpapis solution of installing apple-gcc42 using Homebrew (apparently, gcc42 was removed starting Xcode 4.2). After that, rvm installs 1.8.7 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rvm did not find `apple-gcc42` installed with brew.

Make sure `gcc-4.2` is available via `PATH`, or run installation with path to it:

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7 --with-gcc=/path/to/brew/apple-gcc42/gcc-4.2
```

---

EDIT1:
just checked, RVM searches also for `gcc-apple-4.2` so if it is on `PATH` it will be automatically used by RVM - this was updated in RVM 1.16.8.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the GCC package, installing/uninstalling Xcode, etc, but what I think worked was:

```
rvm get stable
```

(The response included another command:

```
sudo sed -i'' -e "s#rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')#rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')#" /etc/rvmrc
```

)

I'm pretty sure this was what led to being able to successfully:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: This was what helped me indeed. Doing `rvm get stable` and then it just worked.